# Youtube Content Partner API Documentation

Tags: youtube-api, content-management-system

Trying to find the documentation for the YouTube Content partner API. I am a content partner and I'm working with a developer to create a system, we're able to make content owner report  calls on the analytics API, so I know my authentication works and I'm allowed to view and turn on the Content Partner API in the API console. I really need to do the following:

> "The YouTube Content Partner API allows the management of YouTube assets along with their associated content, references, ownership, rights and policies."

but when I click through to Learn more the URL https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/ returns a 404 "Page not found

> The page you requested was not found on this website.
>
> Error: 404 Not Found"

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: what's the url you are visiting that links to "learn more"?  have you tried https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/?

Comment: I wish i could add images but the "learn more" links to https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/

Comment: Also, none of these options "The YouTube Content Partner API allows the management of YouTube assets along with their associated content, references, ownership, rights and policies." are documented as API calls in the other analytics/data API's so there seems to be specific details in Content Partner Api that i can't find

Answer (score 0):

The URL https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/ is working fine.
All the information about functions and methods is located in "Reference" section.